# Pin image to top of a view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am fairly new to SwiftUI and am building a Widget, but I cannot figure out how to pin an image to the top of a view, this is what I've tried but it just defaults to the center of the widget, how can I pin it to the top?

```
var body: some View {
            
       Image("nav_logo")
         .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `VStack` and `Spacer`.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {     
        Image("nav_logo")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

        Spacer() /// will push the image up
    }
}
```

Comment: This kind of worked but it pushed the rest of the content to the bottom, which I dont want

Comment: @NoahIarrobino try putting "the rest of the content" just above the `Spacer()` instead of below it